# Using (linq?) with ef entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a fairly complex sql statement with joins.  Here is my code using EF:

```
var MicrositeResponseAdors = _context.MicrositeResponseAdor
    .Include(user => user.UserTracking)
        .ThenInclude(tracking => tracking.AddTradeIn)
    .Include(user => user.UserTracking)
        .ThenInclude(tracking => tracking.TrackingFinance)
    .Include(user => user.UserTracking)
        .ThenInclude(tracking => tracking.SearchTracking)
    .Include(user => user.UserTracking)
        .ThenInclude(tracking => tracking.TrackingType)
    .Include(user => user.UserTracking)
        .ThenInclude(tracking => tracking.Vehicle)
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id && m.FirstName.ToLower() != "test" && m.LastName.ToLower() != "test");
```

I need to add another join to a table that has no primary key, which Entity Framework doesn't allow.  I wasn't even able to fake it.  So I was told to make something more custom using what I believe is called LINQ?

I cannot figure out how to assign my data values with the original EF entity classes. Here is what I have so far:

```
var MicrositeResponseAdors = (from p in _context.MicrositeResponseAdor
    join c in _context.UserTracking on p.Id equals c.UserTrackingId
    into pc
    select new {
        MicrositeResponseAdor = p, MicrositeResponseAdor.UserTracking = pc 
    }
).FirstOrDefault();
```

This gives:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator.

I think that is because of the first part of MicrositeResponseAdor.UserTracking.  I am not sure how to assign UserTracking under the MicrositeResponseAdor.

Comment: Joins in an ORM are an extremely strong smell. ORMs deal with *objects* that have *relations*. ORMs aren't databases and LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL.

Comment: You need to add another *relation* to the MicroSiterResponseAdor class. Probably just a `public UserTracking UserTracking {get;set;}`. EF will detect the relation if the tables, fields follow the conventions, which they seem to do. The query won't have to change at all

Comment: BTW the EF code you posted doesn't show any joins. Only a *single* entity load. All those `Includes` force eager loading, they have nothing at all to do with joins. You could even get rid of them if you don't require eager loading

Comment: Yeah, it works fine using the ORM, but we have to add another relation which is not there, that relation does not have a primary key.  We cannot fix it at this time because of time restraints and management, so we need a temporary work around, that work around is not using the ORM but instead trying to load it through LINQ.

As for EF and the Include, I'm pretty sure from reading other articles that the Include does a LEFT OUTER JOIN in the SQL behind the scenes. I need all of those things joined, plus one more, which doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: You misunderstood the articles. `Include` is used *ONLY* to force eager loading. It may or may not do that with a LEFT or INNER join but you *can't* depend on that. Such strategies *do* change 
 from one version to another. Without the relation, `Include` will only raise an error. Finally, JOIN can be generated if eg your `select` needs data from the related classes. The ORM can do whatever it deems appropriate to return the results you specified.

Comment: As for time - you already spent a lot more time trying to force joins using an unrelated function and omitting schema, class, mapping information from the question. Specify the relation. You *can* specify composite keys just as you can specify composite foreign keys and joins. Besides - isn't `UserTracking.ID` a key? If not, what is?

Comment: `that work around is not using the ORM but instead trying to load it through LINQ.` but LINQ is just a query language that the ORM translates to SQL. You *can't* use LINQ without the ORM. Besides, have you *tried* just adding `UserTracking` as a property?

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help.  It would take a few months of programming to add the primary key to that table.  It is not UserTracking we are adding it to but Vehicle, which is not listed here.  We need to connect through VIN, and EF will not connect.  So the lead developer told me to use this LINQ code instead.  My only problem is, I can't seem to get the stuff I am pulling into entities.  I think maybe the MicrositeResponseAdor is going in, but the UserTracking is giving an error when I try to load it like this.  The error is in the post.

Comment: what Vehicle? You have one class, `MicrositeResponseAdor` and one property, `UserTracking` that maps to another class also called `UserTracking`. It's the `UserTracking` that needs a key. Doesn't it already have one? Check how the [Foreign Key Attribute]( http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) works. You don't need months, just 1 minute, to ensure you have the `MicrositeResponseAdor.UserTrackingId` and `MicrositeResponseAdor.UserTracking` properties, and add the `[oreignKey("UserTrackingId")]` attribute

Comment: MicrositeResponseAdor is a class, as is UserTracking and an array of others which are listed in the first code I posted.  But I have to add a join to another table which will include an entity class that is not in the code there.  This other table does not have a primary key, and it is being used by a ton of different apps within the company preventing us from simply "flicking the switch" to make a primary key.  We would have to go through each app and check how it will be affected.  This would take months, which we don't have.  We need a quick fix right now.

Comment: If you are in a hurry, post enough details so people can help. You haven't posted *any* class, no schema, no context configuration. Just a couple of queries

Comment: In the second portion of code I posted, it uses LINQ.  I just need to know how to make that LINQ code save into the same entity classes as it was before.  Right now it only saves the MicrositeResponseAdors class, but not the UserTracking class.  I'm not sure how to get that to save so that each table I join from the db will populate the entity classes in my code.

Comment: After so many comments for me it's "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 0):

The error you've given is a C# compilation error, as you're trying to name a property `MicrositeResponseAdor.UserTracking`. Property names can't contain dots.

This would at least compile:

```
var micrositeResponseAdor = (
    from p in _context.MicrositeResponseAdor
    join c in _context.UserTracking on p.Id equals c.UserTrackingId into pc
    select new {
        MicrositeResponseAdor = p,
        UserTracking = pc 
    }
).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will make your `UserTracking` appear in two places:

1. `micrositeResponseAdor.UserTracking`
2. `micrositeResponseAdor.MicrositeResponseAdor.UserTracking`

It's in the first because you've put it there, and it's in the second because there's a relationship between the entities anyway, so EF is conveniently populating it if it has loaded it in that context (and it has, because you asked for it explicitly).

So you don't have to assign loaded navigational properties in your query, you just have to make sure the related entities are loaded, either with a manual join, an `Include` or even a second query.

The question is why you do this at all. You've already had the `Include` version. The join variant is just more verbose, but it doesn't add anything.

Not that EF will always have a key on every entity, whether the database thinks it is one or not. Technically, that's unrelated `Include` vs `join` though.